# JS scoping Q promise issue

Tags: javascript, scope, promise

Please have a look at this jiddle that replicates the problem. The problem is in Scenario #3:

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/timothyoverton/520okekv/3/)

```
function processMultistagePromiseBad(func1data, func2data) {
  console.log("func1data:", func1data);
  console.log("func2data:", func2data);
  return work1(func1data)
    .then(work2(func2data));
}

// scenario 3
processMultistagePromiseBad(data1, data2)
.then((results) => {
  console.log(results);
  return results;
})
.then((results) => scenario3.innerHTML += results + " <br />");
```

For both scenario 3 & 4, I'm passing 2 data objects to a js function, that is calling work1 & work2 functions in a promise chain. Work2 is running in both scenarios but scenario 3 isn't returning correctly....why??

Scenario 4, adding the function declaration is working as expected...?

Thanks,
Tim

Answer (score 1):

.then expects handler functions that will return a value helping to resolve/ exception that will reject the promise - what you are passing here is a promise to the .then and it simply gets ignored. Return the result to resolve the first promise

Refer - 
[chaining promises](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20074685/chaining-promises-with-q-js)

```js
function processMultistagePromiseBad(func1data, func2data) {
  console.log("func1data:", func1data);
  console.log("func2data:", func2data);
  return work1(func1data)
    .then((result) => {
      return work2(func2data);
    });
}
```

EDIT:

Then itself returns a promise. The return value of your resolve/ reject function is passed on to the new promise. The next then in your chain uses this value as input. In processMultistagePromiseBad, work1(func1data) returns a promise with resolve value of "I am data 1". then(work2(func2data)) does not return a new promise with return value "I am data 2" because it is not resturning anything. Therefore processMultistagePromiseBad returns the first promise - "I am data 1" since it was not reassigned by the next then. Whereas in processMultistagePromiseGood it gets reassigned. Promises are really confusing but it comes in handy when we want to execute something async. Hope this helps -  [MSDN documentation on then](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then)

Comment: Hi Sanjana, thanks for your suggestion and link. I'm also looking for an explanation as to why work2 runs, but its return is ignored and instead the return of work1 flows through. Any ideas here? It's an easy hole for a JS developer to fall into and I'd like to understand it more so that I don't make the mistake myself.

Comment: See Edit. I hope this helps you Tim. And please look through the doc because it helped me understand a lot.